# Gatsby + Contentful URL Structure Problems

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I'm having trouble setting up the proper URL structure using Gatsby + Contentful.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├── src
├── pages
├──── Learn (folder)
│    ├── index.js (contentful learn-template queries all pages)
│    ├── guides (folder)
├────└────
├─────────├── index.js (contentful guide-template queries all guides)
```

I'm using `gatsby-node.js` to query my contentful pages with `createPages`:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    const result = await graphql(`
  query GetContent {
page: allContentfulPages(filter: {node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}}) {
    nodes {
      slug
    }
  }
guides: allContentfulGuides(filter: {node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}}) {
    nodes {
      slug
    }
  }
}
  `)

    result.data.page.nodes.forEach(page => {
        createPage({
            path: `${page.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve(`src/pages/guides/index.js`),
            context: {
                slug: page.slug
            },
        })
    })

    result.data.guides.nodes.forEach(guides => {
        createPage({
            path: `${guides.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve(`src/pages/guides/index.js`),
            context: {
                slug: guides.slug
            },
        })
    })
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the URL looks like that:

`http://localhost:8000/learn/{contenfulGuides}/`

But I want to achieve this:

`http://localhost:8000/{contentfulPages}/{contentfulGuides}/`

I've looked everywhere but haven't found topics about this.

I want to know how to remove the folder name in the URL and instead paste the contentful page slug.

Hope someone can help sending me in the right direction.

EDIT:

I think some people don't understand what I meant so I'll explain it a bit more simply here.

I have 2 contentful models, contentfulPages and contentfulSubPages. Each of them holds multiply pages and sub-pages. Now, if I use a template folder and the `gatsby-node.js` from above the URL's looking like that:

`http://localhost:8000/{contentfulPages}/`
`http://localhost:8000/{contentfulSubPages}/`

Two separated URLs. But I want to achieve this:

`http://localhost:8000/{contentfulPages/contentfulSubPages}/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue it's preferable to use the standard way of creating pages in Gatsby, using the `gatsby-node.js` which gives you more flexibility to manipulate the code.

Since your `contentfulPage` is linked to `contentfulSubPages` (one-to-many relationship), you can create nested routes using nested loops as the result of your GraphQL query. Something like:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    const result = await graphql(`
    query GetContent {
     pages: allContentfulPages(filter: {node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}}) {
       nodes {
         slug
         allGuides{
           slug
         }
       }
     }
   }
  `)

    result.data.pages.nodes.forEach(page => {
        createPage({
            path: `${page.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve(`src/templates/page-template.js`),
            context: {
                slug: page.slug
            },
        })
      if(page.allGuides){
         page.allGuides.forEach(guide =>{
            createPage({
            path: `${page.slug}/${guide.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve(`src/templates/guide-template.js`),
            context: {
                slug: guide.slug
            },
        })}
      }
    })
}
```

*Note: this is an approximation, you may need to change a little bit as well as the query and the properties of the GraphQL nodes.*

First of all, you need to loop through `allContentfulPages` (aliased as `pages`) and create a page for each node. Once done that, you can check if that page has subpages, `allGuides` in this case, and make a nested loop to create a nested path (`` path: `${page.slug}/${guide.slug}` `` ).

You can extrapolate the same approach for all your content models.

Answer (score 1):

Files under `pages` are treated as 1:1 with your output. That is, a file at `src/pages/about.js(x)` will produce a page at `/about` when you run a build.

When you want to generate pages with dynamic paths, it's better to put the template files in a `templates` folder, such as `src/templates/guide.js` and provide that path to the `createPage` call in `gatsby-node.js`. The output slug will then match the `path` parameter you pass to `createPage`.

Comment: Okay, but how can I achieve `http://localhost:8000/{contentfulPages}/{contentfulGuides}/` by using the template method?

Comment: Storing my pages in a template folder won't change the `gatsby-node.js` config.

Comment: @patrick The `path` parameter you pass to `createPage` determines the path of the page. If you want to create a page at `/foo/bar/` using the template at `src/templates/foo-bar.jsx` you would just specify `path: "/foo/bar/", component: path.resolve("src/templates/foo-bar.jsx")`. Since I don't know what you mean by `{contentfulPages}` I can't really advise on the query you need to use to fetch that data, alas.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question (which I believe was my fault for explaining it wrong). So imagine you have 2 contentful templates that you query using `createPage`. One is `src/templates/pages.js` and the other one  `src/templates/sub-pages.js`. Now, I'm looking for a way to create URLs that combine both templates like that `http://localhost:8000/{contentfulPages}/{contentfulSubPages}/`.

Comment: I've been searching for days but there's no information on the web about it. In Gatsby's Routing Docs they only talk about nested links using the right folder structure in `pages`. But I want to create nested links using my contentful templates.

Comment: A “template” in this context is for a page. One page, one template. Since this is React, though, you could have a template that has components for each of these types. Because the pages are being built statically, instead of putting the information you need in the URL, you pass it directly. So you would pass the relevant IDs or slugs for each entry to the `createPage` call as `context`, making them available in your page GraphQL query exported from the template file.

Comment: I'm trying right now using the File System Route API method. If that's my query:

  contentfulPage {
    slug
    allSubPages {
      slug
    }
  }

Why is this file structure not working?

{contentfulPage.slug} (folder)
{contentfulPage.allSubPages__slug}.js

Comment: @patrick I don't know the File System Route API so I can't advise on the syntax, but I recommend using gatsby-node.js instead—less magic, you can name your files reasonably, and you have more control.

Comment: Do you know how I can create nested routes using the createPages API?

Comment: @patrick That's what I've been describing.

Comment: I'm reading the docs once again on routing to fully understand all possible ways. Anyway, thanks for your guidance @coreyward